# Is there a non-klunky way to perform special-case formatting with bound data?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, data-binding, formatting

I am binding many controls on my form to an object returned from a method call like so:

```
textBoxMoonBeam.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", pi, "MoonBeam"));
```

*Note: "pi" is the name of an instantiation of the PlatypusInfo class.*

...but when I am grabbing a dateTime value, which by definition includes the time appended to the date, but I only want to show the date in the control, I've got to eschew the type of binding above and instead do this:

```
textBoxDateAztecsFirstSawElvis.Text = pi.DateAztecsFirstSawElvis.ToString("d");
```

Is there a way to bind my data like the first example, and still truncate the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the binding source's `Format` event.

Something like this:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("Text", pi, "DateAztecsFirstSawElvis", true);
binding.Format += binding_Format;
textBoxDateAztecsFirstSawElvis.DataBindings.Add(binding);

void binding_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e) {
  e.Value = ((DateTime)e.Value).ToShortDateString();
}
```